# Change resolution Ubuntu over Teamviewer

Tags: 14.04, resolution, teamviewer

Im running a computer with Ubuntu 14.04.1, no screen attached. I have installed Teamviewer 10.0.36897. Im trying to get it to produce fullscreen when connecting to it through Teamviewer, allthough it only shows 1024x768.

http://s13.postimg.org/ksbsgfq8m/res.jpg

Before connecting to my "Ubuntu-computer" I have - under properties - added 1920x1200, like image below shows, allthough this doesn't help.

http://s22.postimg.org/tsgxpkqpd/upls.png

In Ubuntu under "Screens" the dropdown option to change resolution is grayed out, and Im not able to change there either.

How do I increase the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You must change resolution on computer with Ubuntu 14.04.1.
You have wiki [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.